# kendo chart lines and series hover

Tags: javascript, css, html, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

i'm trying to fix a problem in my kendo chart. On series Hover works fine when mousse is hover the serie, but when I want to know it's value in the line it doesn't appear and I don't know why.

```
$("#chart1").data("kendoChart").setOptions({
        categoryAxis: [{

            majorGridLines: {
                visible: true,
                step: 10
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            labels: {
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            notes: {
                icon: {
                    type: 'square', 
                },
                data:[{
                    value: this.selectionPosStart,
                    label: { 
                        text: 'P',
                        background: color1,
                        color: 'white'
                    },
                    line: {
                        color: color1,
                        length: lenght,
                        width: 2,
                    }
                }, {
                    value: this.selectionPosEnd,
                    label: { 
                        text: 'D',
                        background: color2,
                        color: 'white'
                    },
                    line: {
                        color: color2,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        length: length,
                        width: 2
                    }
                }],
            }
        }],
        valueAxis: {
            majorUnit: 1
        },    
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the tooltip attr, e.g.

```
tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
```